# Java SSLException Host name doesn't match the certificate subject, but it does

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

Getting back this javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'mywebsite.azurewebsites.net' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.azurewebsites.net), but *.azurewebsites.net does match me. I'm only one subdomain deep as in error and should be a match.

I am using the org.apache.http library.

EDIT: My httpcore/httpclient library files were out of date (4.4.1). I updated and the issue was resolved. I believe this to be a previously resolved bug in the apache http library.

Comment: There could be a problem with the TrustManager. Could you share the code where exactly you are getting this exception?

Comment: I added an edit to the post. This seems to be an old apache http bug, that updating my library reference resolved. Thank you for the quick response though!

Comment: Thanks for letting me & the community know about the problem and solution. This could help somebody else in the future... I appreciate !!

Comment: You could also answer your own question